SeleniumBase: Web Crawler being affected by human verification system (Select Similar Images)
While crawling a courier website using SeleniumBase for taking screenshot of tracking page, the bot is getting detected and "Select Similar Images" verification box is being shown.
URL: https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/tracking-results/QF085212272GB
Code:
from seleniumbase import SB
fallback_ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36'

chromium_arg = '--disable-gpu,--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled'
with SB(uc=True, headless2=True, agent=fallback_ua, chromium_arg=chromium_arg) as sb:
    url = "https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/tracking-results/QF085212272GB"
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 3)
    sb.sleep(1)

    sb.save_screenshot('ss.png')

Expected screenshot:

Actual screenshot:

Versions

Dockerized environment: python3.9-slim

seleniumbase: 4.28.0

Chromium Browser: Chromium 126.0.6478.126 built on Debian 12.5, running on Debian 12.5

Chrome Driver: ChromeDriver 126.0.6478.126 (d36ace6122e0a59570e258d82441395206d60e1c-refs/branch-heads/6478@{#1591})



What have you tried so far to circumvent your issue?

Although you also asked and I answered from the GitHub page (SeleniumBase/discussions/2892) already, I'll post the solution here in case anyone else runs across it:
It looks like you're changing things that you shouldn't be. Use this instead:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    url = "https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/tracking-results/QF085212272GB"
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
    sb.save_screenshot("myimage.png")

Don't use headless mode, don't change the default user-agent, and don't set chromium args in UC Mode. The default settings of UC Mode maximize your chances of bypassing bot-detection.
